# how to see function body through dblink using select text from all_source query

Tags: oracle, toad

I am using following query to get details of function (which is on another database) through dblink

`SELECT text 
FROM all_source
where name = 'FUN_INSERT_XXDETAIL@XXDBLINK'
order by line;`

Comment: I'm not sure this question is accurately labeled as a duplicate....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the `database link` at the wrong place.

```
SELECT text 
FROM all_source@XXDBLINK
WHERE NAME = 'FUN_INSERT_INTERFACEDETAIL'
order by line;
```

Comment: Please mark it as answered if it has helped you.